# Initialize union with array?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am new to C++. I want to create a data structure for network communication (TCP), where I can build up a byte array from small tagged pieces (like in serialized class). And of course I need a reverse behavior of this. I need tagged pieces from a byte array, that's why a I put a constructor to the union.

```
typedef union message {
  struct {
    int header;
    int payload;
  } pieces;
  int whole[2];

  message (int* arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      whole[i] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  message ():iVal(){}
} Message ;

main() {
  int a[2] = {10, 2};
  Message msg(a);
}
```

This snippet is working. But I'm curious: is there any better solution to initialize a union by array?

Comment: If the code works and you want to improve, try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: What would you use this `union` for? Remember that you are not allowed to read a `union` member other than the one last assigned to!

Comment: C and C++ handle unions differently. It's not a Yoda-esque case of "You must unlearn what you have learned! Hmmmm!" but more a "Half the sneaky smurf I used unions for in C is not guaranteed to work in C++."  Off topic: You don't need to do the `typedef union uAA { ... } UAA;` trick in C++. `union uAA { ... };` does it all for you.

Comment: I think a different way of asking the same as BaumMitAugen would be: Are you confusing struct and union? You have "union" in title and code, but "struct"ure in your question.

Comment: Actually I know the difference. But You were right. I corrected it.

Comment: May I ask why you are using a union? Why don't you simply use a regular class with a regular constructor and regular members?

Comment: This is not a proper use case for a C++ union.

Comment: I am not familiar with the possibilites in c++ that is why I asked the question. Basically at the end what I need is a byte array. And I wanted to avoid the serialization because the lack of the resources. But maybe I am wrong.